# Attempted to make calls on more than one thread in single threaded mode. (RPC_E_ATTEMPTED_MULTITHREAD) SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, sharepoint-server, multithreading

Experiencing problem above after two web parts on the same aspx page deploy. Both parts use this code:

```
using (var portal = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = portal.OpenWeb())
                {
                    _settingsList = web.Lists[SettingsListName];

                    var query = new SPQuery
...
```

User fails to load page with error

> "Attempted to make calls on more than one thread in single threaded mode. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010102 (RPC_E_ATTEMPTED_MULTITHREAD))"

Appreciate any suggests.

Comment: Are you elevating code somewhere? Do you have any static objects?

Comment: I don't use any elevations but actually my _settingsList is static.

Comment: Seems work fine after removing all static fields and wraps! It helped me) Amal, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Static objects then the associated `SPSite/SPWeb/SPList` object will get used by different threads (in your case two web part code might get executed in different threads).

Hence to resolve you can try removing static.